# Set based stacking update query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that needs one of two Flag values are set, `Flag1` and `Flag2`.

```
   Create Table StackUpdateTable
       (Id Int, GroupId Int, Flag1 Bit, Flag2 Bit, Requirements Int)
```

Now, here are the rules:

1. `Requirements` will be **either** a 1 *or* a 2.
2. `Requirements` specifies the number of preceding `Flag1` values that must be set before a `Flag2` value can be set for a given `GroupId` in `Id` order (ascending).
3. Once `Flag2` is set, the sequence starts again (for each `GroupId`)

I've been trying to wrack my head on if there's a way to do a set based Update on this table (and all new ones that come in) that can set the flags for each set of `GroupId` records.

To further illustrate, consider the following data:

```
Insert Into StackUpdateTable Values
     (1, 100, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(2, 100, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(3, 101, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(4, 102, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(5, 102, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(6, 102, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(7, 103, 1, 0, 1)
    ,(8, 103, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(9, 103, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(10,104, 1, 0, 2)
    ,(11,105, 1, 0, 2)
    ,(12,106, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(13,106, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(14,106, 0, 0, 2)
    ,(15,106, 0, 0, 2)
;
```

Given this data, here's what the resulting Updated data should look like

```
 1 100 1 0 1 <-- Flag1 Set
 2 100 0 1 1 <-- Flag2 Set
 3 101 1 0 1 <-- Flag1 Set
 4 102 1 0 2 <-- 1st Flag1 Set
 5 102 1 0 2 <-- 2nd Flag1 Set
 6 102 0 1 2 <-- Flag2 Set
 7 103 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 8 103 0 1 1 <-- Flag2 Set
 9 103 1 0 1 <-- Flag1 Set
10 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
11 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
12 106 1 0 2 <-- 1st Flag1 Set
13 106 1 0 2 <-- 2nd Flag1 Set
14 106 0 1 2 <-- Flag2 Set
15 106 1 0 2 <-- 1st Flag1 Set
```

If more data is added, thusly...

```
Insert Into StackUpdateTable Values
     (16,100, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(17,103, 0, 0, 1)
    ,(18,106, 0, 0, 2)
;
```

...then the updated dataset (in `GroupId` \ `Id` order) should look like:

```
 1 100 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 2 100 0 1 1 <-- Unchanged
16 100 1 0 1 <-- Flag1 Set
 3 101 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 4 102 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
 5 102 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
 6 102 0 1 2 <-- Unchanged
 7 103 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 8 103 0 1 1 <-- Unchanged
 9 103 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
17 103 0 1 1 <-- Flag2 Set
10 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
11 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
12 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
13 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
14 106 0 1 2 <-- Unchanged
15 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
18 106 1 0 2 <-- Flag1 Set
```

Finally, if the following row should be inserted:

```
Insert Into StackUpdateTable Values
     (19,106, 0, 0, 2)
;
```

then I'd expect:

```
 1 100 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 2 100 0 1 1 <-- Unchanged
16 100 1 0 1 <-- Flag1 Set
 3 101 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 4 102 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
 5 102 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
 6 102 0 1 2 <-- Unchanged
 7 103 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
 8 103 0 1 1 <-- Unchanged
 9 103 1 0 1 <-- Unchanged
17 103 0 1 1 <-- Flag2 Set
10 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
11 104 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
12 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
13 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
14 106 0 1 2 <-- Unchanged
15 106 1 0 2 <-- Unchanged
18 106 1 0 2 <-- Flag1 Set
19 106 0 1 2 <-- Flag2 Set
```

I've been fritzing with using Windowing functions such as `Row_Number() Over (Partition By GroupId Order By Id) As _seq` to organize the data, then a couple of `Lag` functions `Lag(Flag1, 1, 0) Over (Partition By GroupId Order By Id) As _Calc1` etc but I fall over trying to handle new records (where the values start off with a zero).

I think I need to start doing record counts as well, but am unsure how to handle that - thinking that I might be able to do something with `_seq` perhaps, but still getting no-where.

What I'd like is to find out how I could do a Set based Update each time I parse this table. It doesn't have to be a single update, in fact I'm more than happy to drop a Temp table in the mix, or a CTE or anything else. The one thing I **don't** want to do is do have to cursor my way through this, either by `Id` or `GroupId`.

I'm quite prepared to hear that what I ask for just cannot be done, however I live in hopes!

Comment: How close have you been able to get? Posting some of the queries you've tried and how they've failed might help.

Comment: Using Flags is a pretty good indication that the design is less than ideal. Given this design you could have different requirements for a given GroupID on different rows which really sheds some light that this design is in need of some help.

Comment: Trust me, what I had really won't help - just as I got into thinking I'd gotten a solution I realized that doing a Lag(Flag1, 1, 0) on a unset (e.g. 0) value was still going to produce a 0. My queries I'd tried thus far all ended up driving me further into a rabbit hole of zero result.

Comment: @SeanLange This is the hand I've been dealt with by the business and it absolutely totally cannot change. I wish it could but it can't. There's a lot more to this than I've detailed, but this is an integral piece of the puzzle. Names of columns have been changed to protect the purpose and needs.

Comment: This seems like it could be done pretty simply? For example, even without updating the table or whatever, it seems you could do it with something like `SELECT ID, GroupID, Flag1 = CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Flag2 = CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Requirements FROM (SELECT *, RN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID, Requirements ORDER BY ID) - 1) / Requirements FROM StackUpdateTable) AS T;`

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it was just groups of n (where n = requirements) but it looks like you're saying only 1 Flag2 gets set before it goes back to setting Flag1 n times... In that case, it'd be something like: `SELECT ID, GroupID, Flag1 = CASE WHEN RN > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Flag2 = CASE WHEN RN = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Requirements FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID, Requirements ORDER BY ID) % (Requirements + 1) FROM StackUpdateTable) AS T;`

Comment: @zlk interesting - let me play around with this some more. Please do add it as an answer because, if it does indeed solve my question then I'll be more than happy to shower you with some StackOverflowBucks (aka points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ZLK's query from the comments, I converted it to an `UPDATE` statement that you can run after each time records are added to the table.

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Flag1 = CASE WHEN t.RN > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ,s.Flag2 = CASE WHEN t.RN = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY GroupID, Requirements ORDER BY ID ) % ( Requirements + 1 )
    FROM StackUpdateTable
) T
INNER JOIN StackUpdateTable s ON s.Id = T.Id
```

Comment: Thanks! If it's OK with you I'm going to hang on for a short while to see if @ZLK posts their answer (as an answer). If they don't then I'll give you the ol' 'Accepted' points, but since they did come up with the code first (albeit as a comment) then I'd at least like to try and wait to see of they come back to claim their prize!

Comment: I think you don't need to join to the original table here. Just update T.